# How to get the latest records of each column in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

I got two columns for my regular table and I would like to know the latest record of each column, what SQL command should I use? The schema of the table is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work: what you've tried, where you're stuck, errors, output issues, etc. Also, please edit to use properly-formatted text to represent your table and data, not an image of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
select last(c1) from tbname
```

this query will retun the last non-null value of c1

or you can try

```
select last_row() from tbname
```

the query will return the last row of the table no matter the column is null or not